# Unable to use multiple select statements to insert data into a table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

So I'm trying to insert data into the Main_Contract_Data table from three different tables and it is producing an error that is shown below, does anyone know why?

Error:
Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

//SQL Server 2008 Code

```
INSERT INTO Main_Contract_Data
        (organisation_name,
         contract_start_date,
         a_manager,
         d_manager)
   (SELECT [Client]
            FROM [Internal].[dbo].[RequiredFields$])
   (SELECT [Start Date] 
            FROM [Internal].[dbo].[RequiredFields$])
   (SELECT person_id
            FROM A_Manager
            WHERE person_id = '5')
   (SELECT person_id
            FROM D_Manager
            WHERE person_id = '6')
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make those sub queries:

```
INSERT INTO Main_Contract_Data
        (organisation_name,
         contract_start_date,
         a_manager,
         d_manager)
SELECT
   (SELECT [Client]
            FROM [Internal].[dbo].[RequiredFields$]),
   (SELECT [Start Date] 
            FROM [Internal].[dbo].[RequiredFields$]),
   (SELECT person_id
            FROM A_Manager
            WHERE person_id = '5'),
   (SELECT person_id
            FROM D_Manager
            WHERE person_id = '6')
```

But keep in mind that each sub query can only return **one row,** while the overall query needs to return an entire result set. If that's only one row too, that's fine, but the overall `SELECT` is to return *one or more* while each sub query returns *one row, and one value* for each row in the overall query.